# Check if item is in sorted list?

Tags: python, performance, sorting

If you have a list such as this:

```
foo_list = [x for x in xrange(2, 2000000000, 2)] ## [2, 4, 6, 8, ...]
```

And you want to check if an element is inside it, then the following operation needs to do 1 billion comparisons:

```
x = 3
if x in foo_list:
    pass
```

However, since we know that `foo_list` is sorted, we can evaluate the conditional after two comparisons (at most).

Is there a Pythonic way to take advantage of this behavior?  I'm wondering if there's a built-in way to tell the program that we're looking for an element in a sorted list:

```
x = 3
if is_in(x, foo_list, sorted=True)
    pass
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html

Comment: Thanks.  Would not have found this myself, given the obscure name of the class